# Show warnings to colleagues in outlook when trying to book meetings out of office hours

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Not sure if this is possible but I have an issue with colleagues booking me for meetings outside of office hours. I'm in a different time zone than most of them so it's understandable that it happens, but it's getting annoying to have to explain on the regular that it's outside of my office hours. I know you can set working hours but nobody looks at that when sending an invitation. Is there any way to set up my outlook so that others see some form of warning or popup or *anything* that tells them that I'm out of office when they're sending an invitation outside of office hours?

Comment: Create an event on your calendar, for the time you cannot be reached, and then share that event with this person. You can also setup an out of the office response, for the time period, until they get the idea you are not around.

Comment: While a fun idea, this issue is with several colleagues and people even send invitations during office hours when there are other meetings booked so I'm not sure even this solution would solve it :)

Comment: Just decline the meetings. If someone is scheduling a meeting when your not actually available it cannot be that important of a meeting

Comment: Like I hinted in the question, I'm currently declining them with a "I'm out of office this time" template, I'm asking if there's any way to make it easier for my colleagues to see that I'm out of office before sending the initial invitation.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, I didn't found a way to pop up warnings or other things when others create meetings and add people who are out of office.

As a workaround, it's suggested that you could set the time to display when you are out of office in Outlook client, and then other colleagues can know you status when arranging meetings. For more information, please refer to: [Add time away from the office to coworkers' Outlook calendars](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-time-away-from-the-office-to-coworkers-outlook-calendars-69fe38aa-7b5f-4225-8b69-47f47092e65e).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.